# flutter iOS Does Not Persist Camera and Mic Permission Status in inappwebview

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

#### **Expected Behavior:**

The WebView should remember the previously granted camera and microphone permissions, and not prompt the user again for permission.

#### **Actual Behavior:**

On iOS, the WebView asks for camera and microphone permissions every time the app is launched, and the video meeting page is accessed within the WebView. The permission status is not persisted across app sessions.

**Additional Information:**
This issue is specific to iOS and is not observed on Android devices. The behavior is consistent across different versions of iOS.

#### **Code:**

```
 Positioned.fill(
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: Uri.parse(widget.url),
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                  allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                  allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback: true,
                ),
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  // Assign the permissionRequestHandler function
                  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                ),
              ),
              androidOnPermissionRequest:
                  (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                return PermissionRequestResponse(
                  resources: resources,
                  action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
                );
              },
              onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                isLoading.value = true;
              },
              onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                isLoading.value = false;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

#### **Environment:**

Flutter Version: 3.10,
iOS Version: 15.7,
Device: iPhone 7,
flutter_inappwebview: 5.7.2+3

**Notes:**
This issue affects user experience, as users are prompted for camera and microphone permissions every time they access the video meeting page within the WebView on iOS devices. It is essential to ensure a smoother and more streamlined user experience by persisting the permission status across app sessions on iOS.